# Swapping String Value In Java

Tags: java, minecraft

I am making a minecraft plugin where when the server starts, as long as the string ability is equal to "yes" it does an action every 5 seconds, and when you type /nameme-enable, it sets it to yes, and /nameme-disable sets it to no. HOWEVER, I can't seem to change the string value, I saw another person 7 years ago ask another question, but it returns as his, string and adding another value, and his was in a method, here is the code for the command...

```
if(cmd.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("nameme enable")) {
                    String ability = "yes";
                }
                if(cmd.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("nameme disable")) {
                    String ability = "no";
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

You're defining `ability` locally. Declare it outside of the if statement and set its value inside the if statement.

```
String ability = "";
if(cmd.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("nameme enable")) {
                    ability = "yes";
                }
                if(cmd.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("nameme disable")) {
                    ability = "no";
                }
```

Comment: ty wether it works or not, for trying to help, I will try and get back to you later